# change the status of a single on/off switch in a series traversing dom starting from an attribute in jquery 

Tags: jquery, html, traversal

I've a problem with a series of on/off switches in jQuery.

This is the markup of the switches:

```
<div class="switchOnOff">
    <div class="switchLed"></div>
    <p class="switchFeedback"></p>
    <a class="switchButton" rel="on" id="one"><span></span></a>
</div>

<div class="switchOnOff">
    <div class="switchLed"></div>
    <p class="switchFeedback"></p>
    <a class="switchButton" rel="on" id="two"><span></span></a>
</div>
```

This is my js:

```
$('.switchOnOff .switchButton').click(function() {  
    if ( $('.switchButton').attr('rel') == 'off' ) {
        $(this).next('.switchLed').addClass("on");
        $(this).prev('.switchFeedback').html("on");
}

   else if ( $('.switchButton').attr('rel') == 'on' ) {
    $(this).next('.switchLed').addClass("off");
    $(this).prev('.switchFeedback').html(feedbackOn);

}});
```

But this code doesn't work. I tried also with "next", "prev" or "closest" selectors but the DOM traversing doesn't work.
In conclusion I wish to obtain a on/off function that can change the status of a single switch.

I hope I was clear.

Any help will be sincerly apreciated.

Comment: Are you not missing fullstops on the `.switchLed` class selector?

Comment: Thanks Orbling; you were right, it was a mistake on writing; I updated it anymore, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do (UPDATED AFTER THE COMMENT)

```
$('.switchOnOff .switchButton').click(function() {
    var div = $(this).closest('.switchOnOff');
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.attr('rel') == 'off') {
        $this.attr('rel', 'on');
        div.find('.switchLed').addClass("on").removeClass("off");
        div.find('.switchFeedback').html("on");
    } else if ($this.attr('rel') == 'on') {
        $this.attr('rel', 'off');
        div.find('.switchLed').addClass("off").removeClass("on");
        div.find('.switchFeedback').html("off");


    }
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/YpfmD/3/

EDIT for last comment: to set the "First pass" you could do:

```
var switcher = function(el) {
    var div = $(el).closest('.switchOnOff');
    var $this = $(el);
    if ($this.attr('rel') == 'off') {
        $this.attr('rel', 'on');
        div.find('switchLed').addClass("on").removeClass("off");
        div.find('.switchFeedback').html("on");
    } else if ($this.attr('rel') == 'on') {
        $this.attr('rel', 'off');
        div.find('switchLed').addClass("off").removeClass("on");
        div.find('.switchFeedback').html("off");

    }
};
//Set up the various div
$('.switchOnOff .switchButton').each(function() {
    switcher(this);
});
//attach the handler
$('.switchOnOff .switchButton').click(function() {
    switcher(this);
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YpfmD/4/

Comment: Thank you Nicola, but this works only the first time; if I want to change back my choice on the on/off switch it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Nicola, your solution works perfectly...just a question: what's the best way, according to you, for include exactly the same function but not into the .click event? You know, for the first access to the page...

Comment: @bobighorus you mean that you need to set everything up when page  loads?Like a "first pass"?

Comment: Yes, when I load the page I need to set the led and the feedback message automatically (checking the value of  the "rel" attribute), even if I haven't done no click anymore. So it's the same thing but out of the .click() event, but I don't want to repeat the same thing twice but I would like to abstract the process.

Comment: Thanks Nicola, it's a good intuition, but it works in the reverse way in the first pass...

Comment: @bobighorus why are you saying that it works in reverse on the first pass? Maybe i didn't get it right but it looks ok to me http://jsfiddle.net/YpfmD/5/

Comment: Yes it works perfectly except for one case: if I load the page and one of the switches is setting to on (rel=on) the function move it automatically to off :)

Comment: @bobighorus so you don't want to switch `attr('rel')` on the first pass? You can do it like this, but this means that the first click on the link does nothing http://jsfiddle.net/YpfmD/6/

Comment: I need the first time the function does not modify the status but only on the click. I think that the only solution is to make two separate functions. Really thanks you for your attention Nicola ;)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your click event, none of your selectors are relative to the actual item being clicked. That is to say, if you click the second `.switchonOff .switchButton`, chances are that your selectors are going to find the first element (the top one). (e.g. the `$('.switchButton').attr('rel')` will always pull from the first element on the page, despite the event being triggered from the second element)

To correct this, make sure you relate your searches to the element itself. this can be done by supplying the scope parameter:

```
var feedbackOn = 'ON';

$('.switchOnOff .switchButton').click(function(){
  // here's your scope
  var $scope = $(this).closest('.switchOnOff'),
      rel = $(this).attr('rel');

  // now locate the elements you want from within scope:
  if (rel == 'off'){
    $(this).attr('rel','on');
    $scope.find('.switchLed').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
    $scope.find('.switchFeedback').html(feedbackOn);
  }else if (rel == 'on'){
    $(this).attr('rel','off');
    $scope.find('.switchLed').removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $scope.find('.switchFeedback').html('OFF');
  }
  return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3cvvk/2/)**

[screenshot http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/2027/40913258.png](http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/2027/40913258.png)

You also may want to look in to `.removeClass` to remove the on/off classes applied when they're opposite. Without knowing your intent, I didn't add it, but thought I would mention it in case it's desired.

Comment: Thank you Brad, but even this solutions works only the first time I click; if I want to change back my choice on the on/off switch it doesn't work.
Thanks for the "removeClass" suggestion; I effectively use it but I didn't report it in the brief for not adding non relevant details.
p.s.: you forgot the first "$(this)" ;)

Comment: @bobighorus: Yup, just caught it. Apparently coffee's not kicking in yet. That one does work, and there's an example on jsFiddle (link below code).